# ORA-01555 for auto extendable UNDO segment

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have an undo tablespace with the AUTOEXTEND option enabled.
But sometimes I receive error:
ORA-01555 snapshot too old: rollback segment number 5 with name "_SYSSMU234124$" too small...
But how it can be? when space is low, instead of overwriting unexpired undo information, the tablespace auto-extends.

Comment: [This discussion is old but may still be useful.](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:275215756923).

Comment: ++ http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01555_snapshot_old.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
    show parameter undo_retention;
    ALTER SYSTEM SET UNDO_RETENTION = 3600;
  show parameter undo_retention;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how & why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer